# How do I write a Multi threaded Alpha-Beta Search algorithm?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, chess, alpha-beta-pruning

I'm trying to create a chess engine using an alpha beta minimax search algorithm, but the code is too slow. I've done all the optimisations I can think of, but it is still very slow in a single thread. I looked at the source code of some other engines to see how they do it and the chess programming wiki (https://www.chessprogramming.org/Parallel_Search#Parallel_Alpha-Beta), but the the code is beyond my level and I don't understand them. I couldn't find any written sources or code snippets either.

**Can someone explain how to efficiently implement threading in an alpha-beta search algorithm? Thanks.**

Comment: How slow is slow? What language are you writing it in? What features have you implemented?

Comment: Around 3 seconds for depth of 4. It takes minutes with any depth higher than that.
It's written in C# for the unity game engine.
It's just minimax with alpha beta pruning. No transposition or move ordering yet.

Comment: What board representation do you use? 2D array, 1D array, bitboards? If any of the first two then your performance is reasonable. Look into doing more normal optimizations first before doing multithread, multithread will be a  pain to debug. Move ordering is gold and very easy to implement. Also try null move pruning, PVS search, and maybe some other reduction. Are you copying the board or make/unmake move? Do the latter. Lots of info in chessprogramming which you linked to, look around there for more optimizations.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alpha-beta is an inherently sequential algorithm as your alpha and beta values get updated continuously thorough the search and cutoffs are decided based on these values. For this reason getting any speedups by increasing the amount of threads is very hard, and the more threads you throw at it, the smaller the gains will be.

However there's still several ways to do it, most of them fairly complicated and they scale extremely poorly with more threads. The go to algorithm used to be the Young Brothers wait concept, it is a fairly complicated algo and it was used for example by Stockfish until a few years back. However with the increasing amount of cores available on modern computers the scaling was very poor and the code very complex. Today most modern engines use something called Lazy SMP. This algorithm is almost as simple as it can be and scales better than the others.

In lazy SMP all you have to do is start the exact same search as you would normally do, just on multiple threads. It relies on having a working transposition table through which the threads communicate with each other. The threads will never be exactly in sync and the randomness will lead each thread to explore slightly different parts of the search tree and then save their results into the transposition table, where it might be used by another thread. Of course there is a lot of repeating work done by each thread, however it is still better than trying to be clever about splitting the work and slowing down the algorithm, and this is especially true when you start scaling up the amount of threads.

I recommend you take a look at the chess programming wiki, where you can even find some pseudo code on how to implement it.
https://www.chessprogramming.org/Lazy_SMP

Though i should also point out that if what you are looking for is improving your time to depth, implementing multithreading won't do all that much for you (and in some extreme cases it might actually even slow it down!). What you need instead is more aggresive pruning of the search tree and more efficient implementation (eg. no memory allocations, so the garbage collector never has to run, etc.).

Comment: thank you so much! I was having trouble understand the logic behind it. I'll look into Lazy SMP.